# How to avoid adding duplicate rows to a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, sqldatareader

I'm using a SqlDataReader to add row by row into a datatable like follows:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    dataTable.LoadDataRow(reader.CurrentRow(), LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
}
```

This works, but **I need to be able to avoid adding duplicate rows to the dataTable**. I would love to be able to use the Contains or Find methods from the dataTable, but I can't find a way to turn the object[] from reader.CurrentRow() into a DataRow to compare to without adding it to a datatable.

I've looked into the option of making a hashset of the object[]s, and then adding them all at once to the datatable at the end, but I forgot that the default object IEqualityComparer only compares the reference.

Is there a feasible way of doing this without removing the duplicates at the end?

If removing the duplicates is the only way to go, what is the best way to do that?

EDIT:
I'm splitting distinct rows from the database into separate datatables in code. Each row from the query result *is* distinct, but sections of each row are not. Unfortunately I need to do exactly what my question is asking, as the results from the query are already distinct.

Comment: Why don't you let the database take care of it?

Comment: @Gorgsenegger: I'm processing a query that is joining several tables, and processing each chunk of those results that relate to a common factor. Several of the rows contain duplicates from some of the tables, but each row is actually distinct.

Comment: Use SQL `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to guarantee distinct rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a ton of detail, but I hope this is comprehensive.

If you need a single column to be unique, then in your Columns collection in your datatable, specify the column like this:

```
 DataTable appeals = new DataTable("Appeals");
 appeals.Columns["PriorAppealNumber"].Unique = true;
 DataColumn keyField = new DataColumn("AppealNumber", typeof(string));
 appeals.Columns.Add(keyField);
```

If the uniqueness needs to span multiple rows, this is the method:

```
 var myUniqueConstraint = new UniqueConstraint( new DataColumn[] {appeals.Columns[0], appeals.Columns[1], appeals.Columns[2]} );
 appeals.Constraints.Add(myUniqueConstraint);
```

That will enforce the constraints BEFORE you try to commit back to the source database.

Comment: Thanks for addressing my actual question. What I'm doing is definitely a workaround, but after talking with several people, it seems necessary. I'm trying your answer now to see if it works.

Comment: @GrayGox374: Is there a better way to pass all of the data columns in the table to UniqueConstraint's constructor? I have something like 90 columns I need to specify...

Comment: ???  Across 90 columns everything needs to be unique?  I have never seen anything like it.  How do you enforce that in the database?

Comment: Creating the UniqueConstraints did end up working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to actually make sure there are no duplicate rows at all - if you're querying relational database use `DISTINCT` - that will return only unique rows.

Comment: The query I'm processing is a join query from multiple tables. I'm breaking the results back into datatable representations of the tables they originally belonged to. So each row is distinct, but there are duplicate sections within that row that I need to avoid adding to their respective datatables.